# Not a HornetQDestination: HornetQQueue

Tags: java, spring

I am working on a JMS Queue for a requirement on JBOSS AS 7.
I am banging my head against the wall :(
I end up getting this error for the queue. It works fine when all of this configuration is part of the applicationContext.xml. We are avoiding cml config and moving to java config. That is when the issue comes up. Please help!!!

Here is the Queue Config in standalone.xml:

```
    <jms-queue name="ticketOrderQueue">
     <entry name="queue/ticketOrderQueue"/>
</jms-queue>
```

Here is my java spring config class.

```
//JMS Configuration 

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
    JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName("java:/ConnectionFactory");
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();                    //HERE
    return (ConnectionFactory) jndiObjectFactoryBean.getObject();
}

  @Bean
public Queue requestsQueue() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName("queue/ticketOrderQueue");
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setProxyInterface(Queue.class);
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(); 
        logger.debug("The Quues is  :" + jndiObjectFactoryBean.getObject()); 
        return (Queue) jndiObjectFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
        final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(jmsConnectionFactory());
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestination(requestsQueue());
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomerDetailedReportJMSListener queueMessageReceiver() {
        return new CustomerDetailedReportJMSListener();
    }

@Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer jmsListenerContainer() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer dmlc = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    dmlc.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory());
    dmlc.setDestination(requestsQueue());
    MessageListenerAdapter listener = new MessageListenerAdapter();
    listener.setDelegate(queueMessageReceiver());
    listener.setDefaultListenerMethod("onMessage");
    dmlc.setMessageListener(listener);
    dmlc.setConcurrentConsumers(10);
    dmlc.afterPropertiesSet();
    dmlc.start();
    return dmlc;
```

Comment: Please add the exception stack trace or error you are receiving to within the context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a lot of trial and errors, it turned out that my classpath was overloaded with the jms jars. Once I got rid of the extra ones, I no more got the error.